# Entity Framework 5 Entity.Entry slow on disconnected entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am loading some objects from my database:

```
     using (myEntities ctx = new myEntities())
            {
               ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnStr;
               List<myEntity> entities = ctx.myEntities.ToList();
            }
```

If at some later time I want to edit an entity and update the DB my code is:

```
public void Update(myEntity entity)
{
        using (myEntities ctx = new myEntities())
        {
            ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnStr;
            ctx.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

I have noticed that there is a massive increase in time on the
             ctx.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
line if the the total count of entities is say 5000
as opposed to 100 ms if there is just one in the original list. I don't understand why the number of entities in the original list is degrading performance because the updated entity is disconnected.

Comment: How slower is it with 5k entities ?

Comment: 15 secs or so it seems proportional

Comment: Look at https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended you can do batch update with that.

Comment: I am only updating one entity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a lot of navigations proprties I set them to null and it worked quickly.